# Indicate the language translated from translate tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools, translations

The "translate:" tool available to moderators in chat rooms is able to translate to/from many languages, and is also able to auto-detect foreign-language text and translate to English.

This is great, but a small additional feature would be to indicate what language was used for the translation. For example:

> translate: أنا أقول باشتراط استخدام العربي الفصحى في الكتابة على الموقع، وسماح الأسئلة عن اللهجات وما يتعلق فيها
>   I say requiring the use of Mandarin in Arabic writing on the site, and allow questions about the dialects therein

It would be immensely useful if the source language could be included as well, perhaps:

> From Arabic: I say requiring the use of Mandarin in Arabic writing on the site, and allow questions about the dialects therein

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So a bit like this?

[image: (from Arabic) I say requiring...]

The reason it wasn't there is that this actually necessitates an additional API call, but... meh.

Comment: Faster non-bug fix, ever? What happened to 4-6 something?? ;)

Comment: @bluefeet 4-6 mehs